# Intel xdk 3400 apk file too large

Tags: cordova, intel

I made apk with Intel xdk 2893 earlier. It was 3.8 MB. Now I made same code to apk with xdk 3400 the  apk size is 28 MB !!!! 
Why it is so big? N how can I reduce it back.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Projects" -> "Build Settings" and uncheck the "Optimize with Crosswalk" option, so the Crosswalk run-time is not included in the package. That might do the trick for you.